# How login process should look like?

Tags: android, algorithm, authentication

I have problem with how login porcess should look like. I've written client and server and my process of login looks like:

1. Put No phone and password -> Click "Login/Sign up"
2. Client creates User object where I put phone number and password.
3. Client sends request to server i.e integer = 1 -> server is waiting for User object.
4. Client sends newly created User (2)) to Server. Client is waiting for answer (integer)
5. Server is checking if User exist:

   - if yes, next step is check password, if pass is OK Server sends to Client answer 1, and next sends User object from database with User details.
   - if yes, but pass is NOT OK, answer is 0, and nothing is sended,
   - if no, answer is -1, and nothing is sended.
6. Client get answer:

   - int = 1 -->(user exist, pass ok) --> get object, get data from object
   - int = 0 -->(user exist, pass not ok) --> Toast "try again"
   - int = -1 --> (user not exist) -->go to profil
7. If a answer is -1 I open my Profil activity and get details from user, put those details in to User object and sends to Server with request code int = 2 --> write user do user list

Is it good way of login? Should I maybe only sends raw integer as phone number and password instead of User object. Every time when I want to connect to server should I send request code with information what I want to do, or is there another idea to this.

Answer (score 0):

The state "user exist, pass not ok" seams a bit problematic to me.
This way you can split an attack in two phases.

1. try possible user names (your server reveals if the user name exists, independent of the password)
2. for known existing user names try a dictionary of possible passwords.

So I would recommend not to leak the information if a username exists.